# How do I determine if a value is within a range?

Tags: c, comparison

I am relatively new to C, I have to do it for school unfortunately and I am having issues with it at the easiest exercises.

Here I have to check if a number is in a certain interval, for example between 4 and 6. I made it like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int i;

  printf("Value to check Interval \n");
  scanf("%s", i);
  if (i>4 && i<6){
    printf("%s Value is in first interval\n", i);
  }
}
```

The `scanf` to enter the number and check if it is in the interval. But even if I enter a number that is part of it, for example 5, the `printf` doesn't do anything. I tried also to add an else statement for numbers outside the interval, but also there the `printf` did not change anything.

Comment: `scanf("%s", i);` should be `scanf("%d", &i);`. `%s` is for strings while `%d` is for `int`s. Using the wrong specifier invokes undefined behavior. Also note that `i>4 && i<6` is the same as `i==5`.

Comment: You want to pump up the compiler's warning level, read the warnings, understand the warnings an then fix the code accordingly until no more warnings are issued.

Comment: @Osiris changed and it still doesn't work properly

Comment: @alk I get no warning, just the line doesnt get printed and program ends

Comment: Not sure about you guys but it works for me perfectly?

Comment: "*...  pump up the compiler's warning level ...*" To do so pass the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for GCC.

Comment: If you changed it like suggested and also in `printf` it should work. `printf("%d Value is in first interval\n", i);`

Comment: I changed it, probably its just a problem with my environment then now. Will try to change that. Thanks a lot for all

Comment: Also you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `if (i>4 && i<6)` == `if (i == 5)`  There is only one integer value larger than 4 and smaller than 6 :)

Comment: I used CLion to check for any faults and it compiled and ran perfectly. I know there are some errors in your code but my compiler probably fixed them for me.

Comment: @Hypomania: "*my compiler probably fixed them for me*" I do not know of any compiler's doing so.

Comment: @Hypomania Compilers do not fix errors for you, but since it is invoking undefined behavior it may aswell work.

Comment: @Osiris, I take my words back, it works in Release mode but not Debug mode, not sure why though, still no errors or warnings showing up.

Comment: Which documentation to `scanf()` and `printf()` did you read. Why do you use the `s`conversion specifier for an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have declared `i variable as int` and you are taking input as `string` so when it is checking condition it is getting `null` value in `i variable` and not able to enter if block check below code

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

      int i;
        printf("Value to check Interval \n");
        scanf("%d",&i);

      if (i>4 && i<6){
        printf("%d Value is in first interval\n", i);
      }
    }
```

try compiling your code without if condition i variable will return a null value